# How can add extra info to the <html> tag?

Tags: theming

How can I add extra info like `lang="ar" dir="rtl"` to the `<html>` tag like the following?

```
<html{{ html_attributes }} lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code, even though for those specific values, I would find a different way (e.g. setting the language for the shown page).

```
{% html_attributes.setAttribute("lang", "ar") %}
{% html_attributes.setAttribute("dir", "rtl") %}
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
```

Inside `hook_preprocess_html()`, since `$variables['html_attributes']` is an [`Attribute`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.4.x) object, so you can use [`Attribute::setAttribute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/function/Attribute%3A%3AsetAttribute/8.4.x).

```
$variables['html_attributes']->setAttribute("lang", "ar");
$variables['html_attributes']->setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
```